# Как изменить размерность numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Мне нужно из

```
[[639 190]
 [ 44   1]
 [ 71   4]
 ...,
 [863 347]
 [870 362]
 [831 359]]
```

получить

```
[[[639 190]]
 [[ 44   1]]
 [[ 71   4]]
 ...,
 [[863 347]]
 [[870 362]]
 [[831 359]]]
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например так:

```
b = a[:, np.newaxis]
```

Полный текст программы:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[639, 190],
              [44, 1],
              [71, 4],
              [863, 347],
              [870, 362],
              [831, 359]])
b = a[:, np.newaxis]

print(b)
```

У меня вывелось

```
[[[639 190]]
 [[ 44   1]]
 [[ 71   4]]
 [[863 347]]
 [[870 362]]
 [[831 359]]]
```